# Is it possible to restrict user to certain record type while creating new record from lightning lookup field

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lookup, lightning-design-system

We have a scenario where when a user is looking up for a organization it should only look for External Org records which was acheived by Lookup filter in Lightning.

The challenge is when there is no record available then user should be able to Create new one but when they select + New it should allow only External Record type view for the user.

Since Iam new iam not sure if we can acheive this in Lightning for now.

Please find the print screen
When the user clicks New record from the lookup lightning field.
[image]

It popups screen with available two record types but we have to reduce it to one.
like ony External Org.
[image]

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: You can try with revoking access of record type for user's profile.

Comment: But if same user try to create organization from other button, then you want this external record type ...right?

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni if we revoke access than it will apply on all places. I want to restrict only to that lookup fields New record creation.

Comment: @Ayub that is right